# Error in install Lua on windows

Tags: windows, lua, installation

I Download Lua v5.3.0 and compiler and Zip-7 and save all in `C:\\gcc-install-lua` Directory And Open Notepad And Write in this Code :

```
@echo off
    :: ========================
    :: file build.cmd
    :: ========================
    setlocal
    :: you may change the following variable's value
    :: to suit the downloaded version
    set lua_version=5.3.0

    set work_dir=%~dp0
    :: Removes trailing backslash
    :: to enhance readability in the following steps
    set work_dir=%work_dir:~0,-1%
    set lua_install_dir=%work_dir%\lua
    set compiler_bin_dir=%work_dir%\tdm-gcc\bin
    set lua_build_dir=%work_dir%\lua-%lua_version%
    set path=%compiler_bin_dir%;%path%

    cd /D %lua_build_dir%
    mingw32-make PLAT=mingw

    echo.
    echo **** COMPILATION TERMINATED ****
    echo.
    echo **** BUILDING BINARY DISTRIBUTION ****
    echo.

    :: create a clean "binary" installation
    mkdir %lua_install_dir%
    mkdir %lua_install_dir%\doc
    mkdir %lua_install_dir%\bin
    mkdir %lua_install_dir%\include

    copy %lua_build_dir%\doc\*.* %lua_install_dir%\doc\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\*.exe %lua_install_dir%\bin\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\*.dll %lua_install_dir%\bin\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\luaconf.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lua.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lualib.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lauxlib.h %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*
    copy %lua_build_dir%\src\lua.hpp %lua_install_dir%\include\*.*

    echo.
    echo **** BINARY DISTRIBUTION BUILT ****
    echo.

    %lua_install_dir%\bin\lua.exe -e"print [[Hello!]];print[[Simple Lua test successful!!!]]"

    echo.

    pause
```

And Save As cmd file in Directory,Now I Want to run build.cmd in commend Line But I give this Error in Cmd[image]

And After in Lua file that created bin sub directory didn't Have lua.exe file,How I Can Fixed it?

Comment: Please show part of log BEFORE `COMPILATION TERMINATED` message (scroll the text up)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  `'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` this Error is top of terminal

Comment: Obviously you need this program.  Do you have MinGW installed?

Comment: Adding this very useful reference here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua

Answer (score 1):

### How to build Lua under Windows (for dummies)

This method may be not applicable to OP's situation, but the simplest way to build Lua for Windows is using Visual Studio (I assume you already have it installed on your PC).

You need to create new file `luavs.bat` and fill it with content (see below)

```
cd /d full\path\to\lua-5.3.4
notepad luavs.bat
```

Now your lua distrib folder should looks like the following:

```
lua-5.3.4
 |___src
 |    |...
 |___doc
 |    |...
 |___Makefile
 |___README
 |___luavs.bat
```

You must run `luavs.bat` not directly, but from Visual Studio Command Prompt (search for it in "All programs" under "Start" menu).
After the following lines appeared:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>
```

Enter the following commands:

```
cd /d full\path\to\lua-5.3.4
luavs.bat
mkdir C:\Lua
copy /y src\lua53.exe C:\Lua
copy /y src\lua53.dll C:\Lua
copy /y src\luac53.exe C:\Lua
mkdir C:\Lua\lua
```

Now add the folder `C:\Lua` to the beginning of `PATH` environment variable (Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables).

You could run Lua now with `lua53` command.
The folder `C:\Lua\lua` is for Lua modules.

---

The content of `luavs.bat`:

```
@rem Script to build Lua 5.3 under "Visual Studio .NET Command Prompt".
@rem It creates lua53.dll, lua53.lib, lua53.exe, and luac53.exe in src.
@rem (contributed by David Manura and Mike Pall)

@setlocal
@set VERS=53
@set MYCOMPILE=cl /nologo /MD /O2 /W3 /c /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
@set MYLINK=link /nologo
@set MYMT=mt /nologo

cd src
%MYCOMPILE% /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL l*.c
del lua.obj luac.obj
%MYLINK% /DLL /out:lua%VERS%.dll l*.obj
%MYCOMPILE% /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL lua.c
%MYLINK% /out:lua%VERS%.exe lua.obj lua%VERS%.lib
%MYCOMPILE% l*.c
del lua.obj linit.obj lbaselib.obj ldblib.obj liolib.obj lmathlib.obj loslib.obj ltablib.obj lstrlib.obj loadlib.obj
%MYLINK% /out:luac%VERS%.exe *.obj
del *.obj
cd ..
```

Comment: So much easier!